# Copy file with specified name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Im trying to copy files that can look something like this `se1.*`, `Se2.*, SE03.*`.

Now, I try to achieve this with `se*.*`, but the problem is there are other fiels such as `sec.*` that gets copied aswell.

Example: `copy %src%\se*.ort %dest%`

I want to copy only the ones with 2 letters followed by 1 or 2 numbers and the extension.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this shows you the files you want to copy then you can wrap it in a for loop.

```
dir se*.* /b /a-d |findstr /i /r "^se[0-9]"
```